# Error NeonDbError 42P07 setting up NextJS DB with Vercel Postgres

Tags: next.js, vercel

So I've followed all the steps of the Vercel docs for Postgres, and when testing my endpoing I get this:

```
{
  error: {
    name: "NeonDbError",
    code: "42P07"
  }
}
```

This is my endpoint:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';

export async function GET() {
    try {
        const result =
            await sql`CREATE TABLE Pets ( Name varchar(255), Owner varchar(255) );`;
        return NextResponse.json({ result });
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ error }, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

I also have my .env.development.local file with all the necessary variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error code means that the table already existed, so it couldn't be created again

The table is ready to be used, or, if needed to create it again, it would be possible to delete it first:

```js
await sql`DROP TABLE Pets;`;
```

Or to list the existing tables:

```js
const listTables = async () => sql`
    SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'public'
        AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
`;

const results = await listTables();

console.log(results);
```